# How can i include a master changelog file inside another master changelog file in liquibase

Tags: maven-plugin, liquibase

I have a requirement where am pulling changelog files containing changesets as a maven dependency from other project module. I need to include the master changelog file of other project (which has reference to all the changesets in it)in current project from where i will execute the maven liquibase update / rollback or spring boot liuqibase setup. Is there a way to make it work?

I tried to do that like shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><databaseChangeLog
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangeloghttp://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd"> 

   <property name="blob" value="bytea" dbms="postgresql"/>
   <property name="blob" value="blob" dbms="derby"/>
   <preConditions>
   <or>
     <dbms type="derby"/>
     <dbms type="postgresql"/>
   </or>
   </preConditions>
   <include file="db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml"/>
   <include file="db/changelog/changesets/2019-06-001-modeler.changelog.xml"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

But i get error 
Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.SetupException:
Error Reading Migration File: Found 2 files that match db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml

**I have same folder structure in all the projects.**

Answer (score 1):

This was a reported bug a while back and is now fixed with the later versions of Liquibase.
Please try to use the latest Liquibase version and see if the issue goes away.

Below is a reference for Liquibase releases.
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/releases

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase can't understand which of your files with same name it should use. 
If it's possible you should change path to your changelog. 
So if your changelogs are both on path `db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml` try to rename the paths at least. For example use `db/changelog/module1/db.changelog-master.xml` or `db/changelog/db.changelog-module1-master.xml`.